# Allow only LeftLandscape and RightLandscape orientation

Tags: iphone, landscape, screen-orientation

How can I made my app to allow only the landscape orientation but both (left and right)?
so if I rotate 180° the app will be rotate but if I rotate in portrait the app doesn't rotate?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your UIViewController:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

You can learn more about this here: [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:)